# Django what do you suggest for mobile request recognition from view?

Tags: python, django, mobile

I am bit lost to recognise if the url asked is from a mobile or a browser, specially since minidetector hasn't been update for 5 years and since python 3 removed has_key().

So, what would be the best way to detect if it's a mobile and from what browser' mobile it came from ? 
With size screen ?

Is django-mobile worse it ?

Edit : what I want to do is simply catch the mobile browser and redirect to an application store link.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a [fairly up-to-date fork of `minidetector`](https://github.com/remohammadi/django-minidetector) around the same age as `django-mobile`. I've used `django-mobile` in the past and it worked for me, but that was about 3 years ago now.

Comment: Oh ok, because when I read their doc, I was feeling there too many things involved for what I want to do haha